# Handling multiple async calls inside for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous

I have a javascript for loop where I call a function for each lat-lng bound, inside this function I execute THREE async calls to google maps Places API, after all three calls execute I color the bounds green.

Issue is my for loop executes in a sync way and all bounds are colored green in a single tick instead of aiting for all three async calls to resume.

How can I do it so the for loop waits for the async calls to execute before going to the next iteration?

My code:

```
async startScrapingGridLoop()
    {
        const self = this;

        for (var i = 0; i < self.zoneBoundaries.length; i++)
        {
            //Multiple async calls
            await self.scrapeCellWithPlaces(self.zoneBoundaries[i]);
            //After all three async calls end I want to color the bound green
            let currentPolygon = self.polygonsArray[i];
            currentPolygon.setOptions({fillColor: 'green', fillOpacity:0.6});

        }
    },

async scrapeCellWithPlaces(zoneBoundaries)
    {
        const self = this;
        var request = {};
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng({ lat:zoneBoundaries.sw.lat(), lng:zoneBoundaries.sw.lng() }), new google.maps.LatLng({ lat:zoneBoundaries.ne.lat(), lng:zoneBoundaries.ne.lng() }));


        for (var i = 0; i < self.types.length; i++)
        {
                
                
            request = { bounds: bounds, type: self.types[i] };
                
            self.placesService.nearbySearch(request, self.scrapeCellWithPlacesCallback);
            console.log('Scraping bounds for '+self.types[i]);
        }

    },

scrapeCellWithPlacesCallback(results, status, pagination)
    {
        const self = this;
         
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK)
        {      
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
            {
                self.results.push(results[i]);
            } 

            //self.setPlacesMarker(self.results);
            //self.fitPlacesBounds(self.results);
            
            if (pagination.hasNextPage)
            {
                console.log('fetching next set of sets');
                sleep:3;
                pagination.nextPage();

                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
                {
                    self.results.push(result[i]);
                } 
            }
        }
        console.log(self.results);
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You should transform the callback version of nearbySearch to promise version, so await on Promise would work

```
async startScrapingGridLoop() {
  const self = this

  for (var i = 0; i < self.zoneBoundaries.length; i++) {
    //Multiple async calls
    await self.scrapeCellWithPlaces(self.zoneBoundaries[i])
    //After all three async calls end I want to color the bound green
    let currentPolygon = self.polygonsArray[i]
    currentPolygon.setOptions({ fillColor: "green", fillOpacity: 0.6 })
  }
},

async scrapeCellWithPlaces(zoneBoundaries) {
  const self = this
  var request = {}
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng({
      lat: zoneBoundaries.sw.lat(),
      lng: zoneBoundaries.sw.lng(),
    }),
    new google.maps.LatLng({
      lat: zoneBoundaries.ne.lat(),
      lng: zoneBoundaries.ne.lng(),
    })
  )

  for (var i = 0; i < self.types.length; i++) {
    request = { bounds: bounds, type: self.types[i] }

    await self.nearbySearchPromise(request);
    console.log("Scraping bounds for " + self.types[i])
  }
},

nearbySearchPromise(request) {
  const self = this

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    self.placesService.nearbySearch(request, (results, status, pagination) => {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          self.results.push(results[i])
        }
    
        //self.setPlacesMarker(self.results);
        //self.fitPlacesBounds(self.results);
    
        if (pagination.hasNextPage) {
          console.log("fetching next set of sets")
          sleep: 3
          pagination.nextPage()
    
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            self.results.push(result[i])
          }
        }
      }
      console.log(self.results)

      resolve()
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Tried that but still nothing, all polygons in the map turn green at same time, it does seem like now the next call waits for the previous one to end before executing the next one. I edited the OP to show new code

Comment: @gabogabans you should also add the detail of `scrapeCellWithPlacesCallback`

Comment: Added to OP, sorry

Comment: @gabogabans I updated the answer, you could have a look and try

Answer (score 0):

You could try to fetch all the data you need before you process it, using `Promise.all`.

Eg.:

```
async function scrapeGrid() {
  let boundaries = [];
  this.zoneBoundaries.forEach(boundary => boundaries.push(scrapeCellWithPlaces(boundary)));
  const polygons = await Promise.all(boundaries);
}
```